# MySQL Left Join to Union

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a left outer join to a union. The query runs, but does not display the columns from the union.  What am I missing?  This is my query:

```
SELECT p.profile_record_id, 
       p.first_name, 
       p.last_name, 
       l.entry_id, 
       l.when_logged, 
       l.amount, 
       l.reason_text 
FROM   member_profile p 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN authorize_net_log l 
                    ON ( p.profile_record_id = l.profile_record_id ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT assigned_entry_number, 
                               payment_status AS e_status, 
                               'vehicle'      AS type, 
                               profile_record_id 
                        FROM   event_entry 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT '', 
                               co_payment_status, 
                               'driver', 
                               profile_record_id 
                        FROM   event_co_driver) u 
                    ON ( p.profile_record_id = u.profile_record_id ) 
WHERE  l.response_code = '1' 
       AND l.reason_code = '1'
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, since there wouldn't be duplicates in this case, but UNION ALL probably would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should add them to the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT  u.*, p.profile_record_id, p.first_name, p.last_name, l.entry_id, l.when_logged, l.amount, l.reason_text
FROM    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, That's what I was missing.  I guess I was expecting the columns to be added automatically.